# LinkList, Checking for double values

Tags: java, list

I'm writing a code that returns true if the entire link list is stuttered and false if it's not. A stuttered list would be `1,1,2,2,5,5,8,8` , non-stuttered would be something like `1,1,2,2,5,6,8,8`.

I have been playing around with it for quite a while, and can't seem to get it to return the correct statement OR not get a nullpointer exception.

```
    public boolean foo(){
    ListNode current = front;
    ListNode runner = current.next;
    while (current.next.next!=null){   //Looks two ahead for the end
        if(current.data!=runner.data){      //They aren't equal, false
            System.out.println(current.data); //just to see my data
            System.out.println(runner.data);  //debugging only
            return false;
        }
        current = current.next.next; //increase by 2
        runner = runner.next.next;   // increase by 2
        System.out.println(current.data + " ||" + runner.data); //again debugging
    }
    return true; // didn't register false, go ahead and true dat badboy.
}


    public static void main (String[] args){
    LinkedIntList list = new LinkedIntList();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(5);
    System.out.println(list.foo());
}
```

Does someone see an obvious error here? I've tried running my while loop for current.next, as well as increasing my runner and current by one each time instead of two but none of it has worked.

Comment: what is the `perfectStutter` method? you called the method above it foo, should it be perfectStutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `while (current.next.next!=null)`, check `while (runner.next!=null)`. Also, You'll have to match the last two node's data after the `while` loop.

Assuming the list has an even number of elements as you mentioned in your question, the following changes in your code will yield correct output.

```
public boolean foo(){
    ListNode current = front;
    ListNode runner = current.next;
    while (runner.next!=null){   //Looks two ahead for the end
        if(current.data!=runner.data){      //They aren't equal, false
            System.out.println(current.data); //just to see my data
            System.out.println(runner.data);  //debugging only
            return false;
        }
        current = current.next.next; //increase by 2
        runner = runner.next.next;   // increase by 2
        System.out.println(current.data + " ||" + runner.data); //again debugging
    }
    if(current.data!=runner.data){      //They aren't equal, false
        System.out.println(current.data); //just to see my data
        System.out.println(runner.data);  //debugging only
        return false;
    }
    return true; // didn't register false, go ahead and true dat badboy.
}
```

---

A better & clean implementation is as follows:

```
public boolean foo(){
    ListNode current = front;
    while (current != null){
        if(current.next == null)
            return false;
        if(current.data != current.next.data)
            return false;
        current = current.next.next;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Code still returns true when it's false. If I change one of the 5's to a 6, I get this return

3 ||3
5 ||6
true.

Comment: Haven't checked your code block yet, I'll let you know if that works

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

You can't blindly use `current.next.next` without some checks first, since it's entirely possible that either `current` or `current.next` will be null.

If that's the case, you'll get a null pointer issue.

Assuming stuttered means double only (as per your example) rather than any multiple, it can be better down with the following algorithm:

```
def isStuttered(node):
  while node != null:
    # Check if only one item left.

    if node.next == null:
      return false

    # Check if not a pair.

    if node.data != node.next.data:
      return false

    # Advance to next pair, okay as we have 2+ items left.

    node = node.next.next

  return true

stuttered = isStuttered(head)
```

---

As an aside, if "stuttered" meant two *or more* of every item, that's a small change to the algorithm:

```
def isStuttered(node):
  while node != null:
    # Check if only one item left.

    if node.next == null:
      return false

    # Check if not at least two.

    val = node.data
    if val != node.next.data:
      return false

    # Start with second item in set,
    #   advance to either new value or list end.

    node = node.next
    while node != null       # note 'and' must short-circuit
    and   node.data == val:
      node = node.next

  return true
```